# Cannot start SSH tunnel manager mysql workbench Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, workbench

I am trying to connect to my Localhost using mysql workbench, but run into the " Cannot start SSH tunnel manager" every time. I have tried reinstalling workbench with apt-get. I also reinstalled python2.7 and imported paramiko.

Still doesn't work. I am running Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit.

Here is a screenshot of the error message when testing the connection.
http://i.imgur.com/wZIDVHo.png

I am happy to send over error logs, but I have no clue where to find them! ;)

I am using Apache2, phpmyadmin and mysql.

EDIT; I have also tried to run it with sudo-permissions. No change.

~ Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete all your mysql installation previously and start new.

sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist upgrade

**if you install mysql workbench directly from Ubuntu software center**, delete it, and install it using the .deb package at mysql website :http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Yeah. I got it working. Still don't really know how I did it. Removing mysql, localhost and all other webserver-related files.